# Do the initial callbacks of a fragment get called before or after Activity onStart()?

Tags: android, android-lifecycle

https://github.com/xxv/android-lifecycle shows that fragment onAttach, onCreate, on CreateView, and onActivityCreated are invoked prior to activity onStart.  However, I tried logging this:

```
   public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        Log.e("TRACE", "MainActivity onCreate");
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Fragment firstFragment = FirstFragment.newInstance();
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content, firstFragment).commit();
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        Log.e("TRACE", "MainActivity onStart");
        super.onStart();
    }
```

FirstFragment looks like this:

```
public class FirstFragment extends Fragment {

    public FirstFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    public static FirstFragment newInstance() {
        FirstFragment fragment = new FirstFragment();
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Context context) {
        Log.d("TRACE", "FirstFragment onAttach");
        super.onAttach(context);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        Log.d("TRACE", "FirstFragment onCreate");
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        Log.d("TRACE", "FirstFragment onCreateView");
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_first, container, false);
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        Log.d("TRACE", "FirstFragment onActivityCreated");
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    }
```

And it printed this:

1. MainActivity onCreate
2. MainActivity onStart
3. FirstFragment onAttach
4. FirstFragment onCreate
5. FirstFragment onCreateView
6. FirstFragment onActivityCreated
7. MainActivity onResume

Comment: https://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html#Lifecycle

Comment: that link says the same as mine.  It states that fragment onActivityCreated is called before Activity onStart, but my log statements show that it is called after

Answer (score 1):

It depends on **how** the `Fragment` is added to the `Activity`.

There are two common ways to add a fragment to an activity: via a `<fragment>` tag in XML or via a `FragmentTransaction` executed in Java.

If, instead of providing an `R.id.content` view and using a `FragmentTransaction`, you create your `FirstFragment` by using an activity layout like this one:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        class="com.example.stackoverflow.FirstFragment"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

You'll see this in the logs:

> ```
> E/TRACE   ( 6094): MainActivity onCreate
> D/TRACE   ( 6094): FirstFragment onAttach
> D/TRACE   ( 6094): FirstFragment onCreate
> D/TRACE   ( 6094): FirstFragment onCreateView
> E/TRACE   ( 6094): MainActivity onStart
> D/TRACE   ( 6094): FirstFragment onActivityCreated
> E/TRACE   ( 6094): MainActivity onResume
> ```

As for why you're seeing the messages in the order you see them when using a `FragmentTransaction`, it comes down to the fact that the transaction is *asynchronous*; there's no guarantee that it will be executed as soon as you call `commit()`. In your case, the system doesn't actually get around to executing it until after your activity's `onStart()`.

Comment: thank you, it does print that.  https://github.com/xxv/android-lifecycle shows onActivityCreated is called before Activity onStart, is that a mistake or am I misinterpreting the diagram?